# Add data to ADODB Recordset dynamically

Tags: sql, excel, vba, recordset

I wonder if it is possible to add data to an ADODB recordset using a list of named ranges without specifying the names on separate rows.

I have tried to evaluate the name but the recordset takes my variable as a name insted of evaluating it.
This leads to an error as there is no name with my variable name in the database.

```
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

SqlStr = "SELECT * From " & table & ";"
rst.Open SqlStr, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic 'adLockPessimistic

If rst.EOF Then
    rst.AddNew
End If

namedCells = Array("orgNr", "name")

With rst
    For i = LBound(namedCells) To UBound(namedCells)
        MsgBox (namedCells(i) & " = " & Range(namedCells(i)))
        !orgNr = Range(namedCells(i)) 'works fine
        !namedCells(i) = "!orgNr" 'gives error du to "namedCells(i)" is not present in database
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with .fields :

```
For i = LBound(namedCells) To UBound(namedCells)
    MsgBox (namedCells(i) & " = " & Range(namedCells(i)))
    rst!orgNr = Range(namedCells(i)) 'works fine
    rst.fields(namedCells(i)) = Range(namedCells(i))
Next i
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `!` bang operator is just a shorthand notation for an implicit default member call.

When you do this:

```vb
Debug.Print rs!SomeField
```

What's really happening is this:

```vb
Debug.Print rs.[Default].[Default]("SomeField").[Default]
```

Three implicit default member calls - the first against the `Recordset` object is the `Recordset.Fields` property, which yields a `Fields` object reference, which itself has a default member `Item`, that accepts a `String` argument - the `!` bang operator passes the identifier that follows it as the value for this string argument (that's why you need to enclose it in square brackets if it's not a valid VBA identifier name) - this `Item` member yields a `Field` object, which *also* has a default member, `Value`. So the fully spelled-out bang operator notation becomes:

```vb
Debug.Print rs.Fields.Item("FieldName").Value
```

Now, default member calls that *are* parameterized (/indexed) are usually considered fine, so this is perfectly ok as well:

```vb
Debug.Print rs.Fields("FieldName").Value
```

Anything else involves implicit default member calls and makes your code say one thing... and actually do another.

Note that these unqualified `Range` calls you have in that snippet, are [implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference), and this is an extremely common source of bugs.

See [Modern VBA Best Practices: Default Members](http://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/?p=7197) for more info on default members and best practices around them (I wrote that article).

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write this. It is really helpful with some background information :)